# Excel Arabic Column Query .Net

Tags: .net, excel, vb.net

I have Excel Sheet with Arabic text in the columns, When I want to retrieve data in vb.net always facing a problem :

> No Value Given for one or more required parameter

Code Is This:

```
Dim Dta1 As OleDbCommand
Dim Dta1 As OleDbCommand
Using conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Excel + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
    conn.Open()
    Dta2 = New OleDbCommand("Select  Count([إسم الثلاثي للمريض]) From [Sheet1$A:S] GROUP BY  Name HAVING COUNT(*) > 1", conn)
    Dta3 = New OleDbCommand("Select  Count([رقم الهاتف]) From [Sheet1$] GROUP BY  Phone  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1", conn)
    Dim b As Integer = Dta2.ExecuteScalar
    Dim c As Integer = Dta3.ExecuteScalar
End Using
```

The code stops at Dta2.ExecuteScalar

Comment: I expect it’s looking for ‘Name’. What does that represent?

Comment: This code won't even compile. You're declaring `Dta2` as `OleDbCommand`, initializing it, but then attempting to assign an `OleDbDataAdapter` object to it. Did you intend to do `Dta1 = New OleDbDataAdapter(...)` and `Dta1.Fill(...)` (instead of `Dta2`)? You probably want to choose your variables' names more wisely.

Comment: @stuartd (إسم الثلاثي للمريض )is Column header for name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define all variable before use

```
dim st1 as String ="إسم الثلاثي للمريض"   
dim st2 as String ="رقم الهاتف" 

Dta2 = New OleDbCommand("Select  Count(st1) From [Sheet1$A:S] GROUP BY  Name HAVING COUNT(*) > 1", conn)
        Dta3 = New OleDbCommand("Select  Count(st2 ) From [Sheet1$] GROUP BY  Phone  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1", conn)
```